# C# VS 2010 Express not creating users.config file

Tags: c#

I'm writing my first ever C# app using the examples that come from Microsoft's Lync SDK as my template. Let's just say it's been fun.

I've created some settings in the Designer (scope=user), and can access these programatically with:

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.EnableRemoteControl == true)
```

but I have 2 problems:

1) the app isn't creating the user.config file. Clearly I'm missing some vital step here!

2) I can't bind the booleans in the user settings to the check-boxes in the WPF form. try as I might, none of the binding examples on the web work for me.

Does anyone have any pointers they'd care to share??

Comment: Are you sure users.config isn't being created? Where did you look for it? Did you remember to call `Properties.Settings.Default.Save()`?

Comment: Hi Charles.

Yes, my cleanup routine is calling <AppName>.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

And I've dropped to DOS and my "c:\>dir user.config /s /od" flushes out lots of other config files - but not one for this app.

I've also built the app and installed it on a separate machine with the same lack of success.

Comment: Making progress: my cleanup routine wasn't being executed! (I was closing with the "X"). So that's now sorted, and I can now see a user.config file. Next challenge: how to bind the checkboxes in the WPF form!

Comment: I have no experience with WPF, but with WinForms, you would just select the checkbox in the designer, and in the properties grid you would expand "(ApplicationSettings)" and then under "Checked" you'd select the setting to bind it to. The code generated would be something like `checkBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Checked", Properties.Settings.Default, "SomeSetting", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));` - WPF is probably different, but hopefully similar.

Comment: Thanks Charles. Alas, not similar enough. I opted to bind it in code rather than in the WPF. Whilst I could actually get it to work that way, doing so actually broke the forms designer. So I took the hint and did it in code.